# Understanding Xcode 5 debugger & console behavior

Tags: c++, c, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I'm playing with a simple console application in Xcode 5, on Yosemite beta. I set a breakpoint and run the program, as in the following screenshot:

[image: Strange console output]

1. As you can observe, the linked list's `head` is not empty, so why the console has not printed anything? Actually, the output **WILL** appear, but only after this function returns. Why is that?
2. Now in the second image, I just hit return and added a black line. But the debugger does not display the `head` variable already. Why is that?

[image: Strange debugger output]

I can just guess that some kind of optimization is happening behind the scenes. Can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: I think your question is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: @HighPredator, thx! indeed, it answers my first question. If I add \n or fflush(stdout) it prints immediately.